# openssh-server install failure on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, ssh

I get below errors. Can you please help?

```
ashwini@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ssh
[sudo] password for ashwini: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ssh
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,072 B of archives.
After this operation, 99.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package ssh.
(Reading database ... 191087 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ssh_1%3a7.2p2-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ssh (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst: 164: /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst: cannot create /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Directory nonexistent
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server (>= 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error blocking install is in the output you quoted:

```
cannot create /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Directory nonexistent
```

Try creating the directory prior to install:

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/ssh
```

Comment: wow! yes it worked. You made my day!!! Thanks a lot :)